# How to add different characters at the end of text file

Tags: shell

I have a text file with a lot of records.
I want to add `|column1|column2|column3` at the end of the first line and then for the rest of the lines I want to add `|Munich|2017_01.003|City_stats`

I have tried with `sed -i 's/$/|column1|column2|column3/' filename.txt`
But this adds `|column1|column2|column3` in all the lines.

Is there any easy approach to do this?

Comment: With awk that's trivial. Give it a try

Comment: @Tanvir : Since different lines are treated differently, I would do a loop over the lines. Can be done in pure shell, but much easier using awk or Perl or Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` [adresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html) to differentiate between header and data lines. For example (in bash)

```
echo $'a\nb\nc' | \
sed -e '1,1 s/$/|header/' -e '2,$ s/$/|data/'
```

outputs

```
a|header
b|data
c|data
```

Comment: No need for `1,1 s...`  It is sufficient to do `1s/...`.  Could do `sed -e '1s/...' -e '1!s/...'`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to produce the desired output, one using `sed` and the other using `awk`:

```
cat filename.txt
Line #1
Line #2
Line #3
Line #4

sed -e '1,1 s/$/|column1|column2|column3/' -e '2,$ s/$/|Munich|2017_01.003|City_stats/' filename.txt
Line #1|column1|column2|column3
Line #2|Munich|2017_01.003|City_stats
Line #3|Munich|2017_01.003|City_stats
Line #4|Munich|2017_01.003|City_stats

awk 'NR == 1 {print $0"|column1|column2|column3"}; NR > 1 {print $0"|Munich|2017_01.003|City_stats"}' filename.txt
Line #1|column1|column2|column3
Line #2|Munich|2017_01.003|City_stats
Line #3|Munich|2017_01.003|City_stats
Line #4|Munich|2017_01.003|City_stats
```